# 1and1 installing python don't work

Tags: python, shared-hosting

I installed python 2.7.3 sucessfully in my shared host directory (1and1.com) in my ssh when I type ***which python27*** at the same session of python installation it just works fine, but when I start another session it returns nothing. however when I go to the python installation directory it works fine. I don't know why. I am sure that I updated ./bashrc file using

```
echo 'export PATH=$HOME/python27/bin:$PATH' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Do a `less ~/.bashrc` and take a look there, make sure everything looks OK. Or better yet, post that rather than the appending command

Comment: Or do "echo $PATH" to see if your path got updated.

Comment: it works in every session but I have to enter the following command

    source ~/.bashrc

Comment: this is the result of less ~/.bashrc
export PATH=/kunden/homepages/15/d447640846/htdocs/python27/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$HOME/python27/bin:$PATH

Comment: reverse those 2 lines ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is already installed as part of the shared hosting packages.
You can see the details by navigating to `http://[siteid].onlinehome.us/logs/info.py`

See this for more info on [1&1](http://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/linux-c85098/pythoncgis-c37725/what-python-modules-are-installed-on-the-shared-hosting-servers-a595984.html)